# Retired badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

The [Analytical](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/86/analytical) badge has retired, no more to be given to anybody because there is no FAQ anymore, right? That's how I understand the word 'retired'.

Now, why are [Precognitive](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/precognitive) and [Beta](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) not retired? There's no way to earn these badges anymore, at least not on this site. Is that the point, that these badges are still active on some other sites still forming up?

Comment: I could swear I once had the *Analytical* Badge but it must have been revoked! I don't have it now. I read the entire FAQ when I first joined and I think that was my very first badge. Bummer.

Comment: @MichaelClark - I see it on user profiles where it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My sense is that the badges are managed, effectively, platform wide and so those can't be retired because there are new sites in progress on Area 51 and there are sites in Beta. Now, a Stack employee would have to confirm that, but it certainly makes sense to me given the moderator newsletters that talked about badges being rolled out to all sites.

We are not alone... :D